# Test a POST Http request from a local node server in REACT

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I need to make unit tests for some post requests but I don't understand how. I tried with mswjs  but the test passes because I'm missing something and I don't know what. I tried to test the requests in an usual way but I wasn't able to put my conditions there and it was sending only 200 status code.

To start with, this is my folder structure:

```
+main folder  
++nodeServer  
+++public  
+++routes  
++public  
++src  
+++tests
```

This is my try for testing the post request to /subscribe endpoint, where I should send an email as a payload and get the response that the payload was received successfully.

**subscribeFetch.test.js:**

```
import {setupServer} from 'msw/node'
import {rest} from 'msw'

const handlers = [
    rest.post("/api/subscribe",(req,res,context)=>{

                if (!req.body || !req.body.email) {
                  return res(context.status(400).json({ error: "Wrong payload" }));
                }
            
                if (req.body.email === 'forbidden@email.com') {
                  return res(context.status(422).json({ error: "Email is already in use" }));
                }
        
                return res(
                    context.status(200),
                    context.json({email:'gigi@gmail.com'})
                )

    })
]

const server = setupServer(...handlers)

beforeAll(()=>server.listen())
afterAll(()=>server.close())
afterEach(()=>server.resetHandlers())

test('should send post request to the server',async()=>{
    server.use(
        rest.post('/api/subscribe',(req,res,ctx)=>{
            return res(
                expect (ctx.status()).toBe(200)
            )
        }
        )
    )
})

//export {handlers,rest}
```

**This is the subscribe post request function that I need to test:**

```
import { validateEmail } from './email-validator.js'

export const sendSubscribe = (emailInput) => {
  const isValidEmail = validateEmail(emailInput)
  if (isValidEmail === true) {
    sendData(emailInput)
  }
}

export const sendHttpRequest = (method, url, data) => {
  return fetch(url, {
    method: method,
    body: JSON.stringify(data),
    headers: data
      ? {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
      : {}
  }).then(response => {
    if (response.status >= 400) {
      return response.json().then(errResData => {
        const error = new Error('Something went wrong!')
        error.data = errResData
        throw error
      })
    }
    return response.json()
  })
}

const sendData = (emailInput) => {
  sendHttpRequest('POST', '/api/subscribe', {
    email: emailInput
  }).then(responseData => {
    return responseData
  }).catch(err => {
    console.log(err, err.data)
    window.alert(err.data.error)
  })
}
```

**Files from the server:**
app.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const logger = require('morgan');

const indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
const communityRouter = require('./routes/community');
const analyticsRouter = require('./routes/analytics');

const app = express();
global.appRoot = path.resolve(__dirname);

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/community', communityRouter);
app.use('/analytics', analyticsRouter);

module.exports = app;
```

**index.js from routes folder in the server folder:**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const FileStorage = require('../services/FileStorage');

/* POST /subscribe */
router.post('/subscribe', async function (req, res) {
  try {
    if (!req.body || !req.body.email) {
      return res.status(400).json({ error: "Wrong payload" });
    }

    if (req.body.email === 'forbidden@email.com') {
      return res.status(422).json({ error: "Email is already in use" });
    }

    const data = {email: req.body.email};
    await FileStorage.writeFile('user.json', data);
    await res.json({success: true})
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    res.status(500).send('Internal error');
  }
});

/* GET /unsubscribe */
router.post('/unsubscribe', async function (req, res) {
  try {
    await FileStorage.deleteFile('user.json');
    await FileStorage.writeFile('user-analytics.json', []);
    await FileStorage.writeFile('performance-analytics.json', []);
    await res.json({success: true})
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    res.status(500).send('Internal error');
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

Please help me write unit test for subscribe endpoint to match the conditions from index.js file from routes folder in the server folder.

Comment: Your test seems to be missing the "action" and "assertion" parts. If you're testing your Express server, consider using something like `supertest` to perform requests. You can still use MSW to mock HTTP calls but be mindful about which endpoints you want to test and which you actually need to mock.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So,i got the expected result without any library,but i dont know if its a good aproach,but at least it works :
const app = require('../../../personal-website-server/app')
const request = require('supertest')

```
describe('POST /subscribe', () => {
    it('should give 400 status code when email is empty', async () => {
        const email = { email: '' }
        const response = await request(app).post('/subscribe').send(email)
        if (!request.body || !request.body.email) {
            expect(response.status).toBe(400)
        }
    })
    it('should give 422 status code when email is forbidden', async () => {
        const email = { email: 'forbidden@gmail.com' }
        const response = await request(app).post('/subscribe').send(email)
        if (request.body === 'forbidden@gmail.com') {
            expect(response.status).toBe(422)
        }
    })
    it('should give 200 status code when email is valid', async () => {
        const email = { email: 'gigi@gmail.com' }
        const response = await request(app).post('/subscribe').send(email)
        expect(response.error).toBe(false)
        expect(response.status).toBe(200)
        expect(response.body.body).not.toBeNull()
    })
})
```